# installing GWT 2.2.0 plugin on Eclipse 3.4 is not working?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, gwt-2.2

I am trying to install GWT 2.2.0 plugin for Eclipse 3.4 (Ganymede), from **help->Software updates->Available software**, I added this URL: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.4, but it complained with this message "No repository found at this URL".

I tried another trick which is [Installing the Google Plugin for Eclipse from a local update archive](http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-from-zip.html), I tried to install the 3.4 archive under this [link](http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.4/zips/gpe-e34-latest-updatesite.zip), but it does not exist (404 error)!

Can some help me out to install this plugin?

*Remark:* I am positive that I do not have any proxy/firewall restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

You're right.  It looks like the update site is no longer there.  This probably isn't the answer that you're looking for, but I'd recommend upgrading to Eclipse Indigo and using the update site shown here:

http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/getting_started.html

My guess is that since the Ganymede plugin is no longer supported, the update site has been pulled.

Comment: Yeah! this is a problem indeed, what makes things worse is I have to stick to Ganymede for backward computability issues. However, I think it is not my call. Thanks for your suggestion